# ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: python, spyder

I am getting the Connection error while trying to scrap data from website. 
Below is the code I am using.

```
import requests
import bs4


res=requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
type(res)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
type(soup)

print(type(soup))
print(soup.prettify())
soup1=soup.select('title')
```

Below is the complete error message.

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
```

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

Comment: this happens when you get google or other websites ?

Comment: Other websites too. Not able to access any websites.

Comment: Check that you don't have too many opened connections to google hosts, netstat could help to count them.

Comment: Luis It not about google; I am not able to access website.